# Почему не работает perspective?

Tags: html, css, transform

У меня есть родитель, которому я задаю `perspective` и `rotateY(60deg)`. НО "родитель" не выглядит так, как если бы он находился в 3д пространстве. В чем может быть проблема?

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(60deg) perspective(200px);
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как он должен выглядеть?

Comment: С чего это он у вас вдруг не работает? Поищите в гугле: `шайа лабаф на зеленом фоне`... Вот он тоже стоит в перспективе в 3д пространстве... но совсем не выглядит как если бы он находился в 3д пространстве... скорее как на плоскости. Как вы думаете, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 3d пространства в мониторе не может существовать у него же нет глубины нужно комбинировать несколько свойств css чтобы добиться 3d эффекта , например добавив box-shadow он как бы(визуально) парит над родительским элементом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

> Если `perspective()` является одним из мультифункциональных значений, оно должно быть указано первым.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 30px;
  transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(60deg);
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поздравляю с первой тысячей на RuSO!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT 